# Display Command Line Output to HTML (Using Node/Express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, command-line

I'm pretty new to coding and attempting to make an application that displays a Twitch channels chat to a webpage. I am using Node and Express as well as the tmi.js package to get the data from Twitch. So far I have a page that will is just a form where a channels name can be typed in and submitted and then that channels chat feed runs in my command line. However, I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to make this chat feed run on a webpage. I have played around with a lot of different ways so far but no luck. I'm not making a bot or any feature to type into the chat and send a message, just to display the chat feed. Thanks in advance for any tips.

app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const tmi = require("tmi.js");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const channelName = req.body.channelID;
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/twitch-chat.html");
    const client = new tmi.Client({
        connection: {
            secure: true,
            reconnect: true
        },
        channels: [channelName]
    });
    client.connect();
    client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, self) => {
        console.log(`${tags['display-name']}: ${message}`);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}!`);
})
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.88.1">
    <title>Twitch Chat Viewer</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/sign-in/">



    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/docs/4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/4.6/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.6/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.6/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/docs/4.6/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/4.6/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#563d7c">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.6/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/docs/4.6/assets/img/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#563d7c">


    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }
    </style>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="text-center">

    <form action="/" class="form-search" method="post">
        <img class="mb-4" src="images/twitch-image.png" alt="" width="150rem" height="150rem">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Search Twitch Channels</h1>

        <input type="text" name="channelID" class="form-control top" placeholder="Channel Name" required autofocus>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>

        <div id="twitchChat"></div>


        <footer>
            <p>Built with <a href="https://tmijs.com/">tmi.js</a></p>
            <p>&copy; Drake Hopkins</p>

        </footer>
    </form>



</body>

</html>
```

twitch-chat.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Twitch Chat</title>

</head>

<body>



    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Drake Hopkins</p>
        <p>Built with <a href="https://tmijs.com/">tmi.js</a></p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can open a WebSocket connection b/w client and the server. You can use tools like socket.io. Whenever a new message is received in the channel emits that message on the WebSocket. Write logic in webpage to read socket message and print it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I came across socket.io when trying to solve this problem earlier. I will revisit that and try to implement it.